How to change the font of special characters
I'd like to change the font of special and Greek characters to those provided by Latin Modern Math (as seen in $\LaTeX$), but I haven't been able to find it in a file format supported by Mathematica.
Do you have any suggestions?

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I am not sure what exactly you mean. Do you want to change the font in your input cells or in the output? For example, you can set the cell font to "Latin Modern Roman" (which you have to install separately) ...
